# BlackBerry Java Plugin for Eclipse - .net web service

Tags: blackberry

I have a web service that accepts a username and password and if the login credentials are correct, it returns the user's name, status, image and last known gps coordinates.

As for now I am stuck in the "login" button where the application neither proceeds nor throws any error. Simulator produces no result and I am unable to load the app on to my handset.

```java
package mypackage;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javacard.framework.UserException;

import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import javax.microedition.location.Location;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationProvider;

import org.kobjects.base64.Base64;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.pane.TitleView;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.image.Image;

public class LoginTest extends UiApplication 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)  
   {
      //Create a new instance of the app
      //and start the app on the event thread.
      LoginTest app = new LoginTest();
      app.enterEventDispatcher();
   }

   public LoginTest()
   {
      //Display a new screen.
      pushScreen(new LoginTestScreen());
   }
}

//Create a new screen that extends MainScreen and provides
//behaviour similar to that of other apps.
final class LoginTestScreen extends MainScreen
{
   //declare variables for later use
   private InfoScreen _infoScreen;
   private ObjectChoiceField choiceField;
   private int select;
   BasicEditField username;
   PasswordEditField passwd;
   CheckboxField checkBox1;
   ButtonField loginBtn;
   Hashtable persistentHashtable;    
   PersistentObject persistentObject;
   static final long KEY = 0x9df9f961bc6d6baL;
   // private static final String URL="http://prerel.track24elms.com/Android/T24AndroidLogin.asmx";
   String strResult;

   public LoginTestScreen()
   {
      //Invoke the MainScreen constructor.
      super();

      //Add a screen title.
      setTitle("Track24ELMS");

      LabelField login = new LabelField("ELMS Login", LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER); 
      login.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 30));
      login.setMargin(10, 0, 20, 0); //To leave some space from top and bottom

      HorizontalFieldManager user = new HorizontalFieldManager();
      user.setMargin(0, 0, 10, 0);
      HorizontalFieldManager pass = new HorizontalFieldManager();
      pass.setMargin(0, 0, 20, 0);
      HorizontalFieldManager checkbox = new HorizontalFieldManager();
      checkbox.setMargin(0, 0, 30, 0);
      HorizontalFieldManager btns = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);

      LabelField usernameTxt = new LabelField("Username :");
      LabelField passwordTxt = new LabelField("Password :");

      username = new BasicEditField();
      passwd = new PasswordEditField();

      loginBtn = new ButtonField("Login", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
      // btn.setChangeListener(new view listener);

      //checkBox1 = new CheckboxField("Remember me", false,Field.FOCUSABLE);
      checkBox1 = new CheckboxField("Remember me",false);

      user.add(usernameTxt);
      user.add(username);
      pass.add(passwordTxt);
      pass.add(passwd);
      //checkbox.add(checkBox1);
      btns.add(loginBtn);
      add(login);
      add(user);
      add(pass);
      add(checkBox1);
      add(btns);

      // loginBtn.setChangeListener(btnlistener);
   }

   public void saveChecked() {
      persistentHashtable.put("", username.getText());
      persistentHashtable.put("", passwd.getText());
      persistentHashtable.put("BoolData", new Boolean(checkBox1.getChecked()));
      persistentObject.commit();
   }

   FieldChangeListener btnlistener = new FieldChangeListener() {

      public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
         //Open a new screen
         String uname = username.getText();
         String pwd = passwd.getText();

         //If there is no input
         if (uname.length() == 0 || pwd.length()==0) {
            Dialog.alert("One of the textfield is empty!");
         } else {
            final String METHOD_NAME = "ValidateCredentials";
            final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
            final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
            final String URL = "http://prerel.track24elms.com/Android/T24AndroidLogin.asmx";

            SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = null;
            HttpConnection httpConn = null;
            HttpTransport httpt;
            System.out.println("The username" + uname + "password" + pwd );
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            //String usernamecode = Base64.encode(username.getBytes());
            //String pwdEncodeString = Base64.encode(passwd.getBytes());
            request.addProperty("Username", "abc");//First parameter is tag name provided by web service
            request.addProperty("Password", "xyz");
            System.out.println("The request is=======" + request.toString());
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.bodyOut = request;
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            System.out.println("The envelope has the value++++"+ envelope.toString());

            /* URL+  Here you can add paramter so that you can run on device,simulator etc. this will work only for wifi */
            httpt = new HttpTransport(URL+ ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID=S TCP-WiFi");
            httpt.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
            httpt.debug = true;
            try
            {
               System.out.println("SOAP_ACTION    ==   " + SOAP_ACTION);
               httpt.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
               System.out.println("the tranport" + httpt.toString());
               resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
               System.out.println("result    ==   " + resultRequestSOAP);            
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("The exception is IO==" + e.getMessage());
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
               System.out.println("The exception xml parser example==="
                     + e.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println( resultRequestSOAP);

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new InfoScreen()); //Open a new Screen
         }
      }
   };

   //To display a dialog box when a BlackBerry device user
   //closes the app, override the onClose() method.
   public boolean onClose()
   {
      if(checkBox1.equals("true"))
      {
         persistentObject = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(KEY);

         if (persistentObject.getContents() == null) {
            persistentHashtable = new Hashtable();
            persistentObject.setContents(persistentHashtable);
         }
         else {
            persistentHashtable = (Hashtable)persistentObject.getContents();
         }

         if (persistentHashtable.containsKey("EditData")) {
            username.setText((String)persistentHashtable.get("EditData"));
         }

         if (persistentHashtable.containsKey("BoolData")) {
            Boolean booleanObject = (Boolean)persistentHashtable.get("BoolData");
            checkBox1.setChecked(booleanObject.booleanValue());
            if(booleanObject.booleanValue()==true){
               saveChecked();
            }
         }
      }
      Dialog.alert("Goodbye!");
      System.exit(0);
      return true;
   }

   //Create a menu item for BlackBerry device users to click to see more 
   //information about the city they select.

   private MenuItem _viewItem = new MenuItem("More Info", 110, 10) 
   {
      public void run() 
      {
         //Store the index of the city the BlackBerry device user selects
         select = choiceField.getSelectedIndex();

         //Display a new screen with information about the
         //city the BlackBerry device user selects
         _infoScreen = new InfoScreen();
         UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(_infoScreen);
      }
   };

   //Create a menu item for BlackBerry device users to click to close 
   //the app.
   private MenuItem _closeItem = new MenuItem("Close", 200000, 10) 
   {
      public void run()
      {
         onClose();
      }
   };

   //To add menu items to the menu of the app, 
   //override the makeMenu method.


   //Create an inner class for a new screen that displays
   //information about the city a BlackBerry device user selects.
   private class InfoScreen extends MainScreen
   {
      public InfoScreen() 
      {
         super();
         setTitle("Itinerary");

         LabelField login = new LabelField("Employee Itinerary", LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER); 

         Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img1.jpg");
         EditField statusMsg = new EditField("Status Message", "Update status here");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: We need *way* more information to be able to help you here.  Some code, some indication of what you've done in the debugger, or what logging you've done.  Being unable to load an app on a handset is also a completely different problem from the problem of nothing happening when you press a **login** button.

Comment: Hi Nate, thanks for replying. I was able to load the application onto a OS6.0 handset. However I encountered the following error: "Error - module 'go' attempts to access a secure api". I have the signing keys but somehow the application fails the signature tool. My main concern is to test my code for the "login" button. Please see below my code:

Comment: Hi Name I am unable to add my source code here. Can I email it to you?Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Don't try to add it in comments.  You should be able to go back to the question above, and click the **edit** link below the question.  Then, you can edit your question like the first time you wrote it.  Paste in your code, and then click the button with the **{ }** symbols so that the editor recognizes it as code, and properly formats it.

Comment: Hey Nate, thank you. I have uploaded the code now. I am a complete mess and dont know how to proceed. Please help. A note; if the login is a success, the returned result is "successful" else "not accepted". Depending on the returned result I need to continue from there which is to load a new page with the user's current location coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, nothing is ever setup to respond to your login button being pressed.

First of all, let's remove this *anonymous* class that implements `FieldChangeListener`:

```java
FieldChangeListener btnlistener = new FieldChangeListener() { 
  public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
```

and make it like this:

```java
private class LoginButtonListener implements FieldChangeListener {
  public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    // no change to the content of this method!
  }
}
```

and in the constructor for `LoginTestScreen`, instantiate it, and hook it up to the login button:

```java
loginBtn = new ButtonField("Login", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK); 
loginBtn.setChangeListener(new LoginButtonListener());
```

it looks like you were close, in the commented out code.  Just needed a little more.  Try that, and report back!

**Note:** you *could* make it work with the anonymous button listener class you originally had.  I just don't like the readability of anonymous classes when they get that big, especially since your `btnListener` member was declared in a totally different place than all your other ones.  The real missing piece was the call to `setChangeListener`.  I just wanted to differentiate what I'm recommending, from what's needed.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH:) I have been struggling with this. It navigates to the new page but I cannot see the response anywhere from the webservice. Can you please guide? This is my first BlackBerry application and I am finding it hard.

Comment: @user1478133, You're welcome.  It sounds like your program is now getting further.  However, the way stack overflow is setup, it's not efficient to ask follow-on questions in the comments.  What they want you to do is *Accept* and/or *Vote Up* the answers that help you (although it might be that new users can't up vote yet).  That gives us points for having helped you.  Then, take your new code, that has the `setChangeListener` problem fixed, and post a new question, stating clearly that now you simply aren't getting a server response.

Comment: also, since there were two answers here, that addressed different parts of your question, you may need to chose to Accept one or the other.  but, after you get some more points, you can come back to this question, and give both answers votes if you found them both useful.  that would be considered super nice etiquette :)

Comment: I tried to check the returned response if(resultRequestSOAP.equals("credentialaccepted")) then openNewScreen else show a message that login not accepted. It throws  APP error 104 Uncaught: NullPointerException

Comment: Thank you Nate. I just read your comments. I have voted for your answer:) I hope I have done it the right way. I'll create a new question for the server response.

Comment: @user1478133, actually, until you earn some points on stack overflow, I don't think you're allowed to vote (I don't see any votes for my answer).  but, you **are** allowed to *accept* an answer.  to do that, you check the little checkmark ("V") icon next to the answer, just below the up and down arrows for voting.

Comment: Yes Nate its been hardly 2-3 days since I created my account here. I have accepted your answer as it helped me solve my problem. Cheers.